# Is it possible to use a variable as a default parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I am using ["BrowserSession"](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.ca/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html) and added 2 variables to track the username and password, to login to a site.

```
    private string _username;
    private string _password;

    public StoredAccountInfo RefreshAccountData(string username = _username, string password = _password)
    {
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            //throw Exception("Password Or Username Not Set");
        }
        BrowserLogin(username, password);//In case user is not logged in
        StoredAccountInfo retdata = new StoredAccountInfo();
        //populate retdata
        return retdata;
```

I also added this function which sets the _username and _password variables

```
    public void BrowserLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        if (Cookies == null)
        {
            //Do Site Login Here If not Logged In
            Get(constants.BaseUrl);
            FormElements["UserName"] = username;
            FormElements["PassWord"] = password;
            Post(constants.loginUrl);
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
        }
    }
```

However

```
public StoredAccountInfo RefreshAccountData(string username = _username, string password = _password)
```

gives me the syntax error
"`default parameter value for 'username' must be a compile-time constant`"

Anyone know a workaround or solution? I don't want to pass the username and password Every single time I call the RefreshAccountData method, however in case it gets called before the first browser login, I would like to be able to set the username and password variables from it.

I might just be completely missing a really simple way to do this as well. But I can't seem to think of any.

Comment: How about you just overload the method?  Stop trying to make optional parameters do something they weren't meant to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how overloads work.. I find them fairly confusing oddly enough, although I will look into it. However there's a lot of answers that will do what I need suitably.

Comment: @JasonBrown I have never seen someone that learned optional parameters but not overloading... You are supposed to learn overloading first.

Comment: @Sweeper Learning myself via trial and error, I've been jumping around a bunch of languages (java/c++/c#/etc). But I found out about optional parameters before I knew about how overloading worked.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick Answers. I should finally look into overloading, I've been putting it off for a bit too long I guess.

Comment: There's nothing complicated about overloading.  If you can write two methods then you can overload.  It's just two methods with the same name.  That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloaded methods:

```
public void BrowserLogin(string username, string password)
{
...
}

public void BrowserLogin(string username)
{
  BrowserLogin(username, _password);
}

public void BrowserLogin()
{
  BrowserLogin(_username, _password);
}
```

Parameter object:

```
public class LoginParams 
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}

public void BrowserLogin(LoginParams aParams)
{
  if (aParams.UserName == null)
    <use this._username>
  if (aParams.Password == null)
    <use this._password>
...
}

BrowserLogin(new LoginParams());
BrowserLogin(new LoginParams() { UserName = username });
BrowserLogin(new LoginParams() { UserName = username, Password = password });
```

Comment: Only question I have about this, Not for this situation specifically but more generally, is it possible to only set the password using overloads (so having options to set just username, or just password?) using the parameter names?

Comment: Unfortunately - no. You could do it "javascript" style - see update.

Answer (score 4):

You could default to null and use those variables if null is passed:

```
public StoredAccountInfo RefreshAccountData(string username = null, string password = null)
{
    username = username ?? _username;
    password = password ?? _password;
    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) || 
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        //throw Exception("Password Or Username Not Set");
    }
```

Or you could provide a second method that doesn't take those arguments and pass the variables to your main method, this would let you catch when the caller actually tried to pass a username or password that happened to be null and throw an error.

```
public StoredAccountInfo RefreshAccountData()
{
    RefreshAccountData(_username, _password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables as optional parameters. You have to declare an overload of the method. So sad! :(

```
public StoredAccountInfo RefreshAccountData() {
    return RefreshAccountData (_username, _password);
}
```

There is no way to use optional parameters for this unfortunately.

Let me explain why you cannot. Optional parameter values are put into the compiled code. So if you change the variable's value, the compiled code will not change, right? Long story short, compiled code cannot detect the variable's value has changed.